# Getting HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request in post request in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm trying to create a POST request in rest assured java but receiving HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request. Have tried below two approaches and the same API is working fine in postman. I'm using 4.1.2 rest assured in pom.xml

> curl --location --request POST
> 'http://localhost:8080//api/v1/planning/trips?pageNumber=1&pageSize=40'
>
> --header 'authority: http://localhost:8080' 
> --header 'authorization: Bearer e8c108d6-c380-4715-849b-b6eccd8d2045' 
> --header 'origin: http://localhost:8080' 
> --header 'referer: http://localhost:8080' 
> --header 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' 
> --data-raw '{  "endPlacementTimestamp": 1594994096206,  "startPlacementTimestamp": 1593525296206 }'

**Approach 1:**

```
            RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:8080";
            RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
            httpRequest.header("authority","http://localhost:8080");
            httpRequest.header("authorization","Bearer e8c108d6-c380-4715-849b-b6eccd8d2045");
            httpRequest.header("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            httpRequest.header("origin","http://localhost:8080");
            httpRequest.header("referer","http://localhost:8080");
            JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
            requestParams.put("endPlacementTimestamp", "1594994096206");
            requestParams.put("startPlacementTimestamp","1593525296206");
            httpRequest.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
            Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.POST,"planning/trips?pageNumber=1&pageSize=40");
            int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
//            Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, "200");
            // Retrieve the body of the Response
            ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
```

**Approach 2:**

```
            String body= "{\n" +
    "    \"endPlacementTimestamp\": 1594994096206,\n" +
    "    \"startPlacementTimestamp\": 1593525296206\n" +
    "}";
RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:8080//api/v1/";
Response response = given()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .header("authorization","Bearer e8c108d6-c380-4715-849b-b6eccd8d2045")
        .header("origin","http://localhost:8080")
        .header("referer","http://localhost:8080")
        .body(body)
        .post("planning/trips?pageNumber=1&pageSize=40");[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of it, I have added a JSONObject here so you don't hardcode the payload in the `body()`

```
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080";

    RequestSpecification requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder().addHeader("authority", "http://localhost:8080")
            .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer e8c108d6-c380-4715-849b-b6eccd8d2045")
            .addHeader("origin", "http://localhost:8080").addHeader("referer", "http://localhost:8080")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build();

    JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
    body.put("endPlacementTimestamp", 1594994096206L);
    body.put("startPlacementTimestamp", 1593525296206L);

    given().log().all().spec(requestSpec).queryParam("pageNumber", "1").queryParam("pageSize", "40").body(payload)
            .post("/api/v1/planning/trips");
```

Comment: I tried this way but it is still giving http-status-400-bad-request.

Comment: after doing changes   `JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
//            payload.put("endPlacementTimestamp", "1594994096206");
//            payload.put("startPlacementTimestamp", "1593525296206");`   still facing the same issue.

Comment: Try this `given().log().all().spec(requestSpec).queryParam("pageNumber", "1").queryParam("pageSize", "40").body(body)
    .post("/api/v1/planning/trips").then().log().all();` and tell me what you see as a the output in the console. You'd get the same error but there will extra details this time

Comment: Also I just noticed from your screenshot, the value for the keys are not strings, just remove the quotes, set as `1593525296206L` and send the request and that should hopefully work

Comment: Can we do that tomorrow I'll try to research more. Thanks for trying really appreciate it.

Comment: Request method: POST
Request URI:http://localhost:8080/%2F%2Fapi/v1/planning/trips?pageNumber=1&pageSize=40
Query params:   pageNumber=1 pageSize=40
Headers:authority=http://localhost:8080
               authorization=Bearer 49e2f56f-8f17-42ee-a4c0-ae17955a2a7b
               origin=http://localhost:8080
               referer=http://localhost:8080
               Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8
Body:
{"endPlacementTimestamp": 1593611640000,"startPlacementTimestamp": 1594216440000} <title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title>  Here is the output as requested @WilfredClement

Comment: Not much we can infer from this I'm afraid

Comment: Well i tried another method and I'm getting where I'm putting headers `java.lang.NullPointerException
        at locustTask.SalesCRM.execute(SalesCRM.java:76)
        at com.github.myzhan.locust4j.AbstractTask.run(AbstractTask.java:63)
`    HashMap <String, String> headers;            headers.put("authorization","Bearer cd70f469-b963-48f1-9486-fe5d5e3c443b");

Comment: @Sayen As much as I'd like to help you out with the issue please do not keep me waiting, Kindly let me know if you need any help from me on this or I could move away from this question

Comment: I apologise to kept you waiting but as this a company code my manager didn't approve for the bridge. I'm sorry to kept you waiting. Appreciate your help

Comment: Yes @Wilfred, I was putting slightly wrong path to base URL and. Post part. I followed the above format shared by you and it worked!! Thanks for helping me out. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In approach1:

1. Put RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:8080//api/v1";
2. Last line  .post("/planning/trips?pageNumber=1&pageSize=40");
   Refer https://www.toolsqa.com/rest-assured/post-request-using-rest-assured/

Comment: can you please elaborate? I didn't understand your solution.

Comment: In the working example I can see the url has two slashes after the port number.Use the values provided in my comment and revert back

Comment: I tried this way but it is still giving http-status-400-bad-request

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your postman request and response

Comment: please find the snapshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU7VI.png

Comment: Please post snapshot of body also

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03nik.png here is the post api body

Comment: Try :JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(); //            payload.put("endPlacementTimestamp", 1594994096206); //            payload.put("startPlacementTimestamp", 1593525296206); . I have removed quotes from the values

Comment: Without quotes it is showing error "Integer number too large"

Comment: Declare endPlacementTimestamp and startPlacementTimestamp as long in your pojo

Comment: I tried to handle that with Biginteger but it is still throwing 400